# Remove paper size options on node add forms

Tags: 7, files

Node add forms show some paper size options no matter who the user is, even regular authenticated users. It seems to be part of the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module.

I added the following code to my helper (let's call it `my_helper`) module, [as suggested here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2714635#comment-11179049):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_helper_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hiding the print fields that print.module puts into the node form.
  if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE && !empty($form['print']['print_pdf'])) {
    foreach ($form['print']['print_pdf'] as &$print_field) {
      $print_field['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

I am also using the [Simplify](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify) module to hide certain form elements but this isn't coming up as an option there.

[image]

Edit: I looked at the system table in MySQL to see that the weight of the module was 0, so I added a .install file to change the weight to 10. But still not seeing an affect.

```
   function my_helper_update_7100() {
        db_update('system')
        ->fields(array('weight' => 10))
        ->condition('name', 'my_helper', '=')
        ->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to debug and see that the form structure was actually updated? Or that this code is being hit?

Comment: I checked the module weight in MySQL after running the install and it's still set to 0. I think if I can get it to 10, it might work. But the .install just isn't doing it.

Comment: That is not effective - you need to know that the code is being hit, the condition is being entered, and that the form is updated. Without that, it is not worth checking on the weight of the module. Start with devel, dump the form before the end of the function and inspect the print items to see that they were actually set to FALSE

Comment: I think this uses `dpm()` function somewhere right?

Comment: Yes, that is one of the functions

Comment: I mean to "Start with devel, dump the form before the end of the function" do I insert `dpm()` after `$print_field['#access'] = FALSE;`?

Comment: Yes. you will want to dump `$form['print']['print_pdf']` out at the end of the hook - after you believe you've written over the elements. That will tell you for a fact if the code is working as intended, because you will see the modified array.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of a newb. Where do I put dpm exactly? I'm not sure what "dump at the end of the hook" means. I tried to Google it. Would it be like this: `function fosterclub_helper_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hiding the print fields that print.module puts into the node form.
  if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE && !empty($form['print']['print_pdf'])) {
    dpm(foreach ($form['print']['print_pdf'] as &$print_field)) {
     $print_field['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}`. That's either wrong or it's not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting my answer from drupal.org as these two pages are the first results in google.
https://www.drupal.org/project/print/issues/2714635

> I just fixed this on my works web site. The form alter code needs to be added in an #after_build callback as the paper size and orientation fields don't exist yet in the form array in using hook_form_alter. Here is a complete example.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // Hiding the print fields that print.module puts into the node form.
  if (strpos($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE) {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'mhfa_pdf_form_alter_after_build_remove_print';
  }
}

/**
 * Remove pdf print controls.
 */
function my_module_form_alter_after_build_remove_print($form, &$form_state) {
  unset($form['print']);
  return $form;
}
```